# SAS Proc means w/ completetypes preloadfmt not outputting 'other' group from user format

Tags: format, sas, proc

I'm doing the following to get an output table that includes 0 obs rows from a specified format.  The output result works for all defined format categories EXCEPT the 'other' category, which in this case is the "null weight" of a scorecard.

```
proc format;
  value var03f
  LOW - 75 = '79'
  75 <- HIGH = '39'
  OTHER = '76'
  ;
run;

proc means data=thismonth completetypes noprint nway;
        class  &thisvar./PRELOADFMT ;                
        by ScoreDate;
        output out=way5(rename=(_freq_=count) keep=ScoreDate &thisvar. _freq_ _STAT_ where=(_STAT_ = "N"));
    run;
    proc print data=way5 l noobs;
        var ScoreDate &thisvar. count;
    run;
```

Any ideas why the catch all isn't showing up?

Thanks,

Comment: LOW to HIGH leaves nothing for OTHER

Comment: I have people falling into OTHER.  Presumably they are missing values, but I haven't checked yet.  I need to look at the raw values.

Comment: If you want to summarize missing class levels you must include the missing option.

Comment: You are right that the LOW to HIGH is keeping proc means from outputting the OTHER group, but if I change the format to be 0 - 99999, the output is still not correct.

There are 37 records with missing values.  They are correctly summarized in a proc format, but this method of proc means is show 0 records in the null weight instead of 37.

Comment: I think you nailed it with the MISSING option.  I usually use proc means for summarizing distributions with the nmiss output explicitly so I've never used the MISSING option.  How do I accept your comment as the answer?

Comment: Yes, adding the MISSING option worked!  Thank you.

Comment: Will you add an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it as the answer to this question?  Thanks again.

Comment: There is a quirk.  On some formats even with LOW to HIGH the MISSING option works and outputs the OTHER category.  On others I have to change the HIGH to 999999 or remove the LOW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to summarize missing class levels you must include the missing option.